# Difference between two ways of creating arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I just encountered a problem about an array in Powershell and I just want to understand what was happening.

Why is this way :

```
$Path = 'C:\'
$File1 = $Path + 'File1.txt'
$File2 = $Path + 'File2.txt'
$Files= @($File1, $File2)
```

Different from this way :

```
$Path = 'C:\'
$Files= @($Path + 'File1.txt', $Path + 'File2.txt')
```

Because with the first one, I can parse it like this :

```
$Files| ForEach-Object {
    $Test = Get-Item -Path $_
}
```

But I can't with the second one, unless I created it like this :

```
$Path = 'C:\'
$Files = @(($Path + 'File1.txt'), ($Path + 'File2.txt'))
```

Is there another clean way to create an array ?
Thank you !

Comment: What is your end goal, and where do you get the list of files from? Posted an answer but think you could improve this further.

Comment: I have to run multiple commands using different configs, so I'm looping through an array with my config files :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first instance, you are creating an array with 2 elements. In the second instance, you are creating an array with a single element. PowerShell is not processing `$Path + 'File1.txt'` as one.

You can check the number of elements in an array by using `$Files.Count`: it will show `2` for the first method, and `1` for the second.

You can get around this by using brackets `()` as you have identified, or using `{}` to wrap the variable:

```
$Files= @("${Path}File1.txt", "${Path}File2.txt")
```

If your plan is to use this in a `ForEach-Object`, you could just use `$Path` in that loop:

```
$Path = 'C:\'
$Files= @('File1.txt', 'File2.txt')

$Files| ForEach-Object {
    $Test = Get-Item -Path "${Path}$_"
}
```

---

**Addendum**

As per Bacon Bits' helpful comment, this is due to [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-5.1), with `,` having a higher precedence than `+`

```
@($Path + 'File1.txt', $Path + 'File2.txt')
```

becomes:

```
($Path) + ('File1.txt', $Path) + ('File2.txt')
```

instead of:

```
($Path + 'File1.txt'), ($Path + 'File2.txt')
```

Comment: That's a great explanation thank you ! But why is it creating one single element despite there is a comma ?

Comment: @NicolasLeucci `,` must have a higher operator precedence than `+`.  PowerShell interprets it as `($Path) + ('File1.txt', $Path) + ('File2.txt')` and not `($Path + 'File1.txt'), ($Path + 'File2.txt')`